# Изменение размера картинки jpeg

Tags: php

Добрый день, мне нужно сделать на сайте так, чтобы пользователь загрузил картинку и она сохранилась на сервере в трёх вариантах: в оригинальном размере, среднего размера (где-то 800x600) и в маленьком(где то 150x200), изображение должно сохранить пропорции.

Посоветуйте, с помощью чего можно это реализовать?

Comment: не знаю или так можно работать в пхп, но на асп, я писал отдельный метод, который занимался изменением размера

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[GD](http://www.php5.ru/articles/image), можно уложится в 50 строк...
А в принципе, это называется [масштабирование](http://blog.webmasterschool.ru/php/65/)